# solution to equations $x(1-y)=0$ and $y(1-x)=0$

Tags: systems-of-equations

I need to solve two equations:

$$
x(1-y)=0 \\
y(1-x)=0
$$

If I had one equation, ex $x(1-y)$, the solution would be $x=0$ or $y = 1$. But how do I go about solving two such equations? Are the solutions as below?
$$
x = 0 \lor y=0 \\
x = 0 \lor y=1 \\
x = 1 \lor y=0 \\
x = 1 \lor y=1
$$

Comment: What is an SLE?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I'm guessing you are referring to the equations actually not being linear, so SLE is not correct term to use. My bad, I edited the question.

Comment: If $x = 0$ and $y = 1$ the first equation is satisfied while the second is not.

Comment: Hint: $x=xy=y$.

Comment: From a quick look $x = y$, $x = 0,1$. And yes using a logical and would be more appropriate here.

Comment: @LennyWhite Yes, I was guessing that SLE stood for “system of linear equations” but was confused by the fact that the equations weren't linear. It's an important point because nonlinear systems can't be solved in the same way that linear ones can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Both* equations in the system need to be satisfied.

- Equation 1 says: either $x=0$ or $y=1$
- Equation 2 says: either $y=0$ or $x=1$

If you choose $x=0$ from equation 1, then you can't choose $x=1$ for equation 2. So $y=0$.

Likewise, if you choose $y=1$ from equation 1, then you can't choose $y=0$ for equation 2. So $x=1$.

If you want to do it with boolean algebra, you have:
$$\begin{aligned}
    ((x=0) \lor (y=1)) \land ((y=0) \lor (x=1))
    &= ((x=0) \land (y=0)) \lor ((x=0) \land (x=1)) \lor ((y=1) \land (y=0)) \lor ((y=1) \land (x=1))
  \\&= ((x=0) \land (y=0)) \lor \text{FALSE} \lor \text{FALSE} \lor ((y=1) \land (x=1))
  \\&= ((x=0) \land (y=0)) \lor ((y=1) \land (x=1))
\end{aligned}$$

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions, and you seem to have noticed how to find them. Just plug in numbers for $x$ (or $y$) that satisfy *one* of the equations, and solve the other :

- If $x = 0$, then your first equation yields $0=0$, so you're left with the equation $y=0$
- If $x = 1$, then your first equation yields $0=0$, so you're left with the equation $y=1$

Of course, if $(x,y)$ is neither $(0,0)$ nor $(1,1)$, the system doesn't have a solution.

So your set of solutions is $\lbrace (0,0), (1,1) \rbrace$.

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting the two equations gives $y=x$.

You have already noticed that $x=0$ or $y=1$ and therefore the solutions are $x=y=0$ or $x=y=1$.